# both if and else condition get ignored in R

Tags: r, database, for-loop, if-statement, operators

First i tried to make a simple if else statement in R but the if condtion always get ignored then i made two if statment but nothing change, the problem is when `is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j] == TRUE` my code enter to both if statement as in the picture and if `is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j] == FALSE`it just increment j.

So i tried to write some print functions to determine the problem but i couldn't, those are the code i used and the output in the console

**d for data frame, k for rows and j for columns**

```
for (d in seq_along(id))
{
  for (k in seq_len(nrow(datamean[[d]])))
  {
    p <- 0
    for(j in 1:4)
    {
      print(k)
      print(j)
      print(datamean[[d]][k,j])
      print(is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j]))
      print(p)
      if( is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j] == FALSE))
      {
          p <- p+1
          print('hello')
          if(p==4) 
          {
            nbs<-nbs+1
          }
      }
      if(is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j] == TRUE))
      {
        print('hello break')
        break
      }
  }
}
}
```

[image: Print function's output in the console]

Comment: You have your `==` inside the `is.na()`, it should be outside. It should be `if( is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j]) == FALSE)` or even just `if( !is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j]) )`. This is just a typo.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: thanks guys your answers were helpful

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should check and try this:

```
for (d in seq_along(id))
{
  for (k in seq_len(nrow(datamean[[d]])))
  {
    p <- 0
    for(j in 1:4)
    {
      print(k)
      print(j)
      print(datamean[[d]][k,j])
      print(is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j]))
      print(p)
      if( is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j]) == FALSE)
      {
          p <- p+1
          print('hello')
          if(p==4) 
          {
            nbs<-nbs+1
          }
      }
      if(is.na(datamean[[d]][k,j]) == TRUE)
      {
        print('hello break')
        break
      }
  }
}
}
```